# Can I split /boot to a different partition on a single partition system?

Tags: linux, boot, partition

I have set up my system, configured it and everything, using only one partition for / (ext4).
So no separate home, boot, swap etc.

So the question is:

Is there a way to go from this configuration to a 'separate' partition set-up?

Can I make room for a separate boot partition and maybe copy my /boot there?

Comment: Why would you do that? Imho it makes much more sense to put /home on a separate partition. Then you may install a newer system, keeping all your files. Or to put swap on a separate partition, where it is easy to wipe everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can shrink your existing filesystem and partition to make room for other partitions, then copy your files. Most filesystems can't be shrunk while they're mounted, so do it from a live CD/USB such as your distribution's or the [GParted live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) (live CD dedicated to partitioning) or [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) (general system administration and rescue live CD).

I do not, however, recommend making `/boot` a separate partition. Making `/boot` separate is only useful if your boot system can't manage to load a kernel from your root partition. The typical circumstances in which this happens are

- You have an old BIOS (firmware) that can't see the whole disk, so you need to put the software that's necessary for booting in a small partition near the beginning of the disk.
- You have a bootloader that can't read your root partition. For example, your bootloader is Grub 1 and your root partition is on an LVM volume.

If your system can already boot with the kernel on the root partition, there's nothing to be gained by creating a separate boot partition.

If you do decide to create a separate boot partition — or, for that matter, if you merge an existing boot partition onto your root partition, there's a bit more to it than just copying the files. When a PC boots, the BIOS loads the boot sector (the first 512 bytes of the boot disk) into memory. There isn't enough room in there to put a whole filesystem driver, so what that code does is to load more code from a location that's stored in the boot sector. If you move that code around to a different partition, you need to update that location. You may need to update your bootloader's configuration file as well.

- With Grub, if your distribution ships with `update-grub` (e.g. Debian or Ubuntu), run it. Otherwise, edit the configuration file (`/boot/grub/menu.lst` for Grub 1 or `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` for Grub 2) and update the device from which Grub will find the kernel. (With Grub 2, you may have nothing to do as it can find the kernel automatically at run time.) In either case, also run `grub-install /dev/sda`.
- With Lilo, run `lilo`.

Comment: I keep `/boot` in a separate partition. It's not for everyone but it has several advantages. Distro upgrades can be tested by rotating root file system while still using tried and true kernels configured for that system (I use mostly custom compiled kernels for each system). The `/boot` partition can be small and out of the way. Using LVM it's easy to migrate the root file system around without worrying about breaking the boot loader. You can also keep a minimal rescue file system on the same partition with busybox and some tools to fix anything that goes wrong with the main root file system.

Comment: @Caleb I used separate `/boot` partitions when I had to due to older BIOSes or Grub1 with root on LVM, but I was glad when I could stop.

Comment: I actually still use `grub1`; not because I have to per-se, just because I haven't bothered to learn and my kernel upgrade/configure/compile/install (including auto updating grub configs with full ability to regress to any kernel and pxe/tftp/netboot scenarios for dozens of machines on three continents) is completely automated by a single script that I would have to teach `grub2` to after I learned it myself.

Comment: I actually want a separate /boot to try trusted-grub, a grub implementation that takes advantage of the TPM chip in my Thinkpad, to measure the kernel etc. It needs a separate /boot partition. I didn't create it when installing, because at that time I had three other primary partitions so I could create only one. Now I deleted the 'recovery' partition of lenovo so I can create a primary boot partition.

Comment: Another reason one might want a separate boot partition is if he needs full encryption of / and the boot partition must be unencrypted.

Answer (score -4):

I haven't tried it, but copying "**/boot**" should work. Be sure to also edit your "**/etc/fstab**" accordingly. I would use some other system (e.g. a live disc) to do this since I don't know how to resize a live partition (if it's even possible/advisable). Also, leave the new boot partition as the first partition ("**/dev/sda**") to avoid *unbootability*.

Comment: Thanks @Tshepang. Can you explain a bit more about that unbootable issues you mention? Now the disk already has two other partitions (windows..) that are sda1 and sda2 so my one linux partition (that I want to split) is sda3.

Comment: When you resize (using a live disc), ensure that the boot partition occupies "/dev/sda3" and rest of your Linux partition occupies whatever else (perhaps "/dev/sda4"). For this, ensure that they remain primary partitions (you should see that option in your partitioning software). This should ensure that your Linux installation will remain bootable.

Comment: This isn't enough, you need to update the bootloader as well! Also Linux doesn't care about the partition number of the boot partition, nor whether it's a primary or logical partition.