# Is the crazy partition layout in Fedora 15 really nessesary?

Tags: fedora, partition

As I'm installing Fedora 15 on another computer I'm really starting to question the crazy partition layout. On this computer there's an existing Windows 7 installation, so I'm cramming Fedora right next to it in a small 15 GB slice of space (don't plan on storing much data there)

But the installer generates this crazy partition layout

- Windows 7 stuff
- Extended Partition

  - /boot (EXT4, 500 MB)
  - LVM(!) Volume Group (14858 MB)
  - lv_root (8660 MB)
  - lv_swap (5888 MB)
  - My home (What's left: 310(!?!) MB)

That doesn't seem like much space. Even on my other system which has a whole 80 GB hard drive to itself the LVM gives the root filesystem and the root folder 50 GB and me a measly 20 GB. I sometimes run out of space when Virtualbox gets a lot of snapshots or bittorrent gets out of control.

Is there anything wrong with a simple layout like this?

- Windows 7 stuff
- Extended Partition (15 GB)

  - Swap (5 GB)
  - Root filesystem (10 GB)

*Note: The sizes can increase if absolutely necessary*. Note the lack of LVM and separate partitions for everything. Will anything break with this layout? Are there any large disadvantages with this layout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LVM is great, but it works best when you have a lot of free space, and you can create small logical volumes that can grow as needed.

Your suggested layout would probably be fine, but I would make a separate /boot partition as well.  (You could also make your swap partition smaller.  You never want to be more than a couple of GB into swap since performance suffers badly past that.  Plus you can always add a swap file if you absolutely have to.)

Comment: Whats the advantage of a dedicated /boot partition? And now that you mention it, I do think that 2-3 GB of swap is more than enough.

Comment: @TheLQ: [the only reasons your /boot should be on a separate partition](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/can-i-split-boot-to-a-different-partition-on-a-single-partition-system/17489#17489)

Comment: Fedora still uses GRUB 1, and the ext4 support is a hack.  I've seen filesystems that it won't read.  A separate /boot isn't going to be written to nearly as much, which minimizes the risk that some random filesystem change is going to render the system unbootable.

Comment: LVM is also great if you want to use a backup program like `baras` where you can snapshot the partition and then you'll know that your VirtualBox images won't have random changes throughout the backup.

Comment: Putting /home on its own partition makes life a lot simpler when you upgrade or migrate across distributions.